# HTTPS Displays on Chrome but not Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

HTTPS Displays on Chrome but not Safari unless I click on another page, and then click back. Then https displays, and I can click it and view the certificate. I installed both the the Webserver Certification and the Intermediate file. Has anyone experienced this problem, and if so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Probably you have some external resource (img, scripts, etc) loaded through plain http. To check try with Chrome or Firefox.

Chrome display a valid green lock on the navbar but on the right side you can see an icon of a shield if there are some resources loaded from an insecure source.
(Firefox display a grey world instead of the lock. Safari instead fails silently removing the https+lock icon) [image: Firefox and Chrome navbars with some resources over http]

Comment: So I just had this problem. Unfortunately I wish you explained how to fix it haha. For anyone who has this problem and wants to know how to quickly fix it, check the page source for errors to see what you are loading thats insecure. So any ajax calls or apis that use non-https methods would be the issue. Great answer though and should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by switching the user agent in the safari menu: Development-User Agent. You may choose any other UA, and for me , the site suddenly displays https. and after I change the UA to general version, it works fine.